# Question about the derivation of filtering roll off

Tags: filter

I don't understand the following step in my notes:

It is about filter roll-off.

$$H(\omega)={1\over 1+j(\omega/\omega_c)}$$

$$\Rightarrow|H(\omega)|= {1\over \sqrt{1+(\omega/\omega_c)^2}}$$

where $$H(\omega) = {v_o \over v_i}$$

$$\omega_c = \text{cut-off frequency} $$

Comment: cross-posted: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/question-about-the-derive-of-filter-roll-off

Comment: Filters become flat roll-off in the log-log scale and the magnitude of slope depends on the order of magnitude of the each power of ω. As this H(ω) has only one occurence of ω in the denominator, we say it has a power of -1 so the gain in the log display is 0dB at ω=0 {as log (1/1)=0} and has a slope of -1 order of magnitude where 20 log (H(ω) means it has a slope of -20dB per decade) which is a 1st order LPF. The intercept or break point is at ωc but we usually use fc instead to show Hz instead of Radians. (Sorry about brief explanation.)

Answer (score 3):

Roll-off is a realizable low-pass filter concept. The simplest low pass filter imaginable is a series resistor followed by a capacitor connected to ground.

```
              R
Vi -------+\/\/\/\+---------+--------- Vo
                            |
                           --- C
                           ---
                            |
                           GND
```

The current through the resistor, \$ \dfrac{V_i - V_o}{R}\$,

must be equal to the current through the capacitor, \$ \dfrac {V_o}{Z_C} \$.

Z<sub>C</sub> is the impedance of the capacitor, which is \$ \dfrac{1}{j \omega C} \$.

So:

\$ \dfrac{V_i - V_o}{R} =  V_o j \omega C\$

... Solve for \$ \dfrac{V_o}{V_i} \$ (an exercise to the reader) and you get:

\$ \dfrac{V_o}{V_i} = \dfrac{1}{1 + j \omega R C} \$

Take the magnitude of the function in the standard ways for complex numbers, and you get the equation with the square root in the denominator.

You *define* the cutoff frequency as the point at which the magnitude of your response is attenuated by some amount. If you define that point such that

\$ \omega_c = \dfrac{1}{RC}\$, then

\$ \left\lvert\dfrac{V_o}{V_i}\right\rvert = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ~= 0.707 \$, or about 70%.

I'm a little rusty here, but I think that if you take the second derivative of \$ \left\lvert\dfrac{V_o}{V_i}\right\rvert \$ you will also find that \$ \omega_c \$ is the point of maximum inflection.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the magnitude, you multiply the expression by the complex conjugate (which you get by replacing j with -j) and take the square root

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{j + \frac{\omega}{\omega_{c}}}\: \: \:\cdot \frac{1}{-j + \frac{\omega}{\omega_{c}}}}\:\:\: = \sqrt{\frac{1}{-j^2 + \left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{c}}\right )^2}}
$$

and since j=sqrt(-1)

$$-j^2 = 1$$

This leaves you at the step I think you're having trouble with, and when reduced gives you the answer:

$$\Rightarrow|H(\omega)|= {1\over \sqrt{1+(\omega/\omega_c)^2}}$$